# Unable to install @types/Module_name in typescript..getting Unrecognized token in source text.error

Tags: powershell, npm, visual-studio-code

For any module I am trying to install its types by `npm install @types/module_name` in my react project, but I'm getting the following error:

> Unrecognized token in source text. At line:1 char:13
>   + npm install  <<<< @types/react-redux
>   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken

I also tried to execute the command with quotations marks: `npm install '@types/module_name'`, but that didn't work as well.

The screenshot with the error:

[image: [Error image]]

Comment: The syntax is `npm install @types/react-redux`. You have `npm install  <<<< @types/react-redux`

Comment: if you open the image and see the console..i have executed the correct syntax..the thing you are talking about is the error that is thrown..kindly check the image

Comment: Open up a powershell window in the containing directory and try it there. Regardless, it works fine in my VS Code integrated terminal

Comment: i dont know why but its not working in my terminal..

Comment: npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...kX\nR1bO6+hhCJ6gWqw/f'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-10T09_59_12_143Z-debug.log

Comment: Sounds like corrupt state. Try `npm cache clean --force` if that fails or doesn't resolve the issue, just repair/install nodejs and check all the boxes. I say that because I have no interest in trying to track this down.